# Hibernate: no persistent classes found for query class: SELECT p FROM entity.Presentation p

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to persist my classes but it always throws me this error.

This is my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Projecten2?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">MyUser</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">MyPass</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>

    <!-- Mappings -->
    <mapping class="entity.Presentation"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And this is the class i am trying to persist

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package entity;


import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.parser.DateTime;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Entity;

/**
 *
 * @author authorName
 */
@Entity
public class Presentation 
{
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    private int id;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private DateTime beginTime;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private DateTime endTime;

    @ManyToOne
    private Location location;
    private int locationId;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<User> users;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "presentations")
    private List<Planning> plannings;

}
```

The query i am trying to execute:

```
Query q = session.createQuery("SELECT p FROM " + Presentation.class.getName() + " p");
presentationModel = new PresentationTableModel((List<Object[]>)q.list());
```

And this is how i get the session to execute queries

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
```

stacktrace of the error message:

```
56 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version - Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.2.0.Final
59 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.6.10.Final
60 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found
61 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : javassist
63 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
93 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
93 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
123 [AWT-EventQueue-0] WARN org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver - recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
141 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configured SessionFactory: null
167 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring
169 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.search.HibernateSearchEventListenerRegister - Unable to find org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener on the classpath. Hibernate Search is not enabled.
171 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
171 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - Hibernate connection pool size: 20
171 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - autocommit mode: false
175 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - using driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver at URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Projecten2?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
175 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
340 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
346 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Database ->
       name : MySQL
    version : 5.6.14
      major : 5
      minor : 6
347 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Driver ->
       name : MySQL-AB JDBC Driver
    version : mysql-connector-java-5.1.23 ( Revision: ${bzr.revision-id} )
      major : 5
      minor : 1
347 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionFactoryFactory - Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
348 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookupFactory - No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional second-level cache is not recommended)
348 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled
348 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled
348 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JDBC batch size: 15
348 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JDBC batch updates for versioned data: disabled
348 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Scrollable result sets: enabled
348 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): enabled
348 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Connection release mode: auto
348 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Maximum outer join fetch depth: 2
348 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Default batch fetch size: 1
348 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Generate SQL with comments: disabled
348 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled
348 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled
348 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
349 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory - Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
349 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Query language substitutions: {}
349 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JPA-QL strict compliance: disabled
349 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Second-level cache: enabled
349 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Query cache: disabled
349 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Cache region factory : org.hibernate.cache.impl.NoCachingRegionFactory
350 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled
350 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Structured second-level cache entries: disabled
353 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Statistics: disabled
353 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled
353 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Default entity-mode: pojo
353 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Named query checking : enabled
353 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Check Nullability in Core (should be disabled when Bean Validation is on): enabled
364 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl - building session factory
367 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [clob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.ClobType@38701425
367 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [java.sql.Clob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.ClobType@38701425
367 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [wrapper_characters_clob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.CharacterArrayClobType@463aa615
367 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [materialized_clob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.MaterializedClobType@346dd0b8
367 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [characters_clob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.PrimitiveCharacterArrayClobType@15a1faec
367 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [blob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.BlobType@3d60a70c
367 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [java.sql.Blob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.BlobType@3d60a70c
367 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [materialized_blob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.MaterializedBlobType@1477244f
367 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [wrapper_materialized_blob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.WrappedMaterializedBlobType@19f0c908
390 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory - Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
438 [AWT-EventQueue-0] WARN org.hibernate.hql.QuerySplitter - no persistent classes found for query class: SELECT p FROM entity.Presentation p
```

I've been searching for quite a bit to fix this but i am not used to using hibernate and i followed their documentation article about mapping but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Paste the exact and complete stack trace of the exception. Note that such a query returns a `List<Presentation>`, not a `List<Object[]>`.

Comment: I added the stack trace, i changed it to List<Presentation> but the result stays the same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As documented for example [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Entity.html), name of the entity defaults to the simple class name. It does not contain name of the package. In this case name of the entity is `Presentation`.

Method [getName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29) in java.lang.Class returns also package, so it is not useful in this case. Better ḿethod for this case is [getSimpleName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSimpleName%28%29):

```
session.createQuery("SELECT p FROM " + Presentation.class.getSimpleName() + " p");
```

As a side note, likely there is no reason to use *org.hibernate.annotations.Entity* instead of *javax.persistence.Entity*.

Comment: Actually, your side note is the real answer to the question: the class is not an entity because it's not annotated with javax.persistence.Entity. Using the fully qualified name is not mandatory, but it's allowed and works fine.

Comment: This solved it indeed :) thank you for the help and the well explained information

Comment: @JBNizet could you ellaborate a bit more, please? What do you mean by "it's not annotated with javax.persistence.Entity"? Does that mean that he should be doing something like `@Entity(name="full.package.name.with.class.name")` in order to be able to use `class.getName()`?

Comment: @Pere no, I mean that the OP used the annotation org.hibernate.annotations.Entity, instead of javax.persistence.Entity, and that is the actual reason why he had an error and asked this question. It's not just a side note. It's the most important part of the answer.